# iterate through values of given key in scala hash map

Tags: scala, hashmap

I need to check all values of a given key to see if the value is already there. With the code i have below i always get the last value added to the key. How to iterate over the entire list of values?

```
val map = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.empty[Int, String]
map.put(0, "a")
map.put(0, "b")
map.put(0, "c")
map.put(0, "d")
map.put(0, "e")
map.put(0, "f")

for ((k, v) <- map) {println("key: " + k + " value: " + v)}
```

output:

```
map: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,String] = Map()
res0: Option[String] = None
res1: Option[String] = Some(a)
res2: Option[String] = Some(b)
res3: Option[String] = Some(c)
res4: Option[String] = Some(d)
res5: Option[String] = Some(e)

key: 0 value: f
res6: Unit = ()
```

Comment: so you want to have some kind of *history* of your map?

Comment: A map cannot contain more than one value for the same key. The last one overrides the previous one. You might want to use MultiMap instead (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.0/scala/collection/mutable/MultiMap.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A key is unique in a `HashMap`. You can't have multiple values for the same key. What you can do is have a `HashMap[Int, Set[String]]` and check if the value is contained inside the set, or even simpler as @TzachZohar points out, a [`MultiMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap):

```
scala> import collection.mutable.{ HashMap, MultiMap, Set }
import collection.mutable.{HashMap, MultiMap, Set}

scala> val mm = new HashMap[Int, Set[String]] with MultiMap[Int, String]
mm: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]] with scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap[Int,String] = Map()

scala> mm.addBinding(0, "a")
res9: <refinement>.type = Map(0 -> Set(a))

scala> mm.addBinding(0, "b")
res10: <refinement>.type = Map(0 -> Set(a, b))

scala> mm.entryExists(0, _ == "b")
res11: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Why is the MultiMap needed? It seems that HashMap[Int, Set[String]] would be enough.

Comment: `MultiMap` is a convenient wrapper around `HashMap[Int, Set[String]]`. You can append data to the set simply by calling `mm.addBinding`, instead of going through the trouble of extracting the set from the `Map` and then appending the new set with the added data.